# Using HTTPSCookiesStorage can I screen(filter) cookies storage in URLSession?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, urlsession, nshttpcookiestorage

I have subclassed HTTPCookiesStorage, but the storeCookies() never store the cookies although, i am calling super.storeCookies() within the method.

Session stores the cookies automatically if i dont override the configuration with my custom httpCookiesSession object. I am kind of lost here.

**This is the URLSession call**

```
   var configration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    //configration.httpCookieStorage = customHTTPCookiesStorage()

    let session = URLSession.init(configuration: configration)



    if let url = URL.init(string: "https://google.com"){
        session.dataTask(with: url) { sip,sap,su in
            print(sip,sap,su)

            var x = session.configuration.httpCookieStorage?.cookies

        }.resume()
    }
```

**This is the custom class**

```
class customHTTPCookiesStorage: HTTPCookieStorage {

    override func storeCookies(_ cookies: [HTTPCookie], for task: URLSessionTask) {

        super.storeCookies(cookies, for: task)
        for cookies in cookies{
            session?.session.configuration.httpCookieStorage?.setCookie(cookies)
        }

        print("This is where cookies are stored")
    }
}
```

**Update 1**
My aim is not to store the cookies in httpcookiesstore when Http response status in 401

Comment: And what happens when you set a breakpoint on the line that calls `super.storeCookies(...)`?

Comment: so cookies are available, in the cookies variable. if I put a breakpoint. but never gets stored automatically. i am sure the for loop i have written in not required but even after successful iterations of for loop, httpcookiesstorage is empty, i was wondering if i am overriding the correct methods and if there is another elegant way of doing so. i just dont want to store cookies in when the status code in 401.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/httpcookiestorage have a look at the **subclassing** section.

Comment: Why is `configration.httpCookieStorage = customHTTPCookiesStorage()` commented out?

Comment: I commented that out to check if the cookies were being stored otherwise. and they were.

I can upload the project in some public repo if you want to check that out?

Comment: Any solution to this?Facing the same issue @HunbleDhillon